# nested table alignment problem

Tags: tables

Following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311296/horizontal-lines-in-nested-tabular-environment) example, I try to extend it a little bit.

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|@{}c@{}| }% <-- aded @{}
\hline
no test & no test & \begin{tabular}{c|c|c} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \end{tabular} \\
\hline
no test & no test & 
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c} D1 & 1.23 & 5 \\ \hline D2 & 1.23 & 6 \\ \end{tabular} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I got this:

[image]

I use `@{}c@{}` in the third column. Why I have two different looks of nested table?

Comment: because the nested table in the second row is wider than in the first row and column width is accommodated to wider table.

Comment: That's because the the nested tables do not have the same width.

Comment: @Zarko: Great minds think together :o)

Comment: @Bernard, its look like :-), however you use fewer words than me to express our thoughts ...

Answer (score 1):

Here some possible solutions, choose what you prefer.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\myone}
\newlength{\mytwo}
\newlength{\mythree}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Table with nested tables with column width 
        as wide as the largest text of the column}
    \centering
    \setlength{\myone}{\widthof{D1}}% larger text of the first column
    \setlength{\mytwo}{\widthof{1.23}}% larger text of the second column
    \setlength{\mythree}{\widthof{6}}% larger text of the second column
    \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|@{}c@{}| }% <-- aded @{}
        \hline
        no test & no test & \begin{tabular}{C{\myone}|C{\mytwo}|C{\mythree}} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        no test & no test & 
        \begin{tabular}{C{\myone}|C{\mytwo}|C{\mythree}} D1 & 1.23 & 5 \\ \hline D2 & 1.23 & 6 \\ \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Table with nested tables with fixed column width}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|@{}c@{}| }% <-- aded @{}
        \hline
        no test & no test & \begin{tabular}{C{2em}|C{2em}|C{2em}} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        no test & no test & 
        \begin{tabular}{C{2em}|C{2em}|C{2em}} D1 & 1.23 & 5 \\ \hline D2 & 1.23 & 6 \\ \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Table without nested tables with multirow and variable column widths}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ |*5{c|} }
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{no test} & \multirow{2}{*}{no test} & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
        \cline{3-5} 
        & & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{no test} & \multirow{2}{*}{no test} & D1 & 1.23 & 5 \\ 
        \cline{3-5}
        & & D2 & 1.23 & 6 \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Table without nested tables with multirow and fixed column widths}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ |*2{c|}*3{C{2em}|} }
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{no test} & \multirow{2}{*}{no test} & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
        \cline{3-5} 
        & & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{no test} & \multirow{2}{*}{no test} & D1 & 1.23 & 5 \\ 
        \cline{3-5}
        & & D2 & 1.23 & 6 \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]